How to statically check with mypy that a dictionary has keys for all options in a Union type?
I have a Union type PossibleOption composed of n dataclasses, and I want to create a dictionary where the keys are instances of these classes. I need to statically check with mypy that the dictionary includes a key for each option in the Union. Here's my current code:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class Option1:
    def __hash__(self):   #don t focus too much on this method, A dictionary need a hashable key. that s all
        return hash(type(self))

@dataclass
class Option2:
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(type(self))

@dataclass
class Option3:
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(type(self))

PossibleOption = Union[Option1, Option2, Option3]

# I want to create a dictionary like this:
a = {Option1(): "a",Option2(): "bb",Option3(): "cc"}
# print(a[Option2()]) prints "bb" for example

I know that I could ask the user to give a function taking PossibleOption as paratmer and returning the the value like that:
 def equivalent_to_dictionary(po: PossibleOption) -> str:
    match po:
        case Option1():
            return "aa"
        case Option2():
            return "bb"
        case Option3():
            return "cc"

and mypy can check is each option are covered
But I want to keep things simple for the user...
Is there a way to statically check with mypy that each option (Option1, Option2, Option3 in this particular case) is present as a key in the dictionary?

Unfortunately, no. TypedDicts don't allow non-string keys. Consider requiring your user to instantiate a normal class instead: Options(option1 = Option1(...), option1_value = ..., ...). On the other hand, if the OptionN classes don't have any fields, as represented here, then they are unnecessary and should be removed. Personally, I think your function approach is really the best solution.

@Insync what do you mean exactly. When I first fried my dictionary it failed because the key was not hashable but after adding def hash(self): it was OK.
you can test my dictionary a. It works
print(a[Option2()]) print bb for example

A dict is only generic in the type of its keys, not in the actual keys. A TypedDict generalizes this, letting you enumerate specific keys that must be present (and giving them each specific types as a bonus), but with the restriction that each key be a string. There is not as yet a way to enumerate a specific set of arbitrary keys that must be present in a dict.

(It's not obvious to me why TypedDict imposes that restriction. Obviously, the class syntax uses identifiers to specify keys, but I'm not sure what problem would be caused by allowing TypedDict('Foo', {Option1(): str, Option2(): int, ...}).)

(Well, aside from the fact that there's no static way to create an instance of your dataclasses.)

Your problem can be modelled with Enum and requiring that some dict is exhaustive (contains all Enum values as keys). I don't know any static solution to that, but it's very easy to assert in a test (literally assert set(typing.get_args(PossibleOptions)) == {type(o) for o in a}). Don't try to enforce everything statically in python - it's a very dynamic language.
